# PHP custom autoload function using spl_autoload_register won't trigger for inherited classes

Tags: php, inheritance, extends, spl-autoload-register

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here, hoping someone can help.

I built the following class with the purpose of detecting when a requested class has not been included so it can be included. I also wanted it to include any inherited classes not included.

The registered onAutoload function triggers as expected when calling a class not already included.

However if calling a class that inherits another class that hasn't been included, the registered onAutoload function does not trigger which is primarily what I want this to do.

I tested this using the default __autoload($class) and it triggers for inherited classes as required.

Any help would be appreciated. Have included a simplified example of what i'm trying to do below and the problem I am encountering.

In Autoload.php file

```
class Autoload
{
    private $fullPath;

    function __construct ($fullPath)
    {
        $this->fullPath=$fullPath;
    }

    public function onAutoload ($class)
    {
        include ($this->fullpath . $class . ".php");
    }
}
```

Autoload class created and registered as required

```
$thisAutoload=new Autoload ("/path/to/file/to/include");
spl_autoload_register(array($thisAutoload,"onAutoload"));
```

Now in the following example, onAutoload is triggered as expected.

```
$newClassToInclude=new ClassToInclude();
```

However in the following example. Assuming ChildClass in included but BaseClass is not included, onAutoload does not trigger.

BaseClass.php

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        print ("Base Class");
    }
}
```

ChildClass.php

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        print ("Child Class");
    }
}
```

I tested this using __autoload() function instead of my custom class and it triggered as expected.

Thanking everyone in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So while not actually a fix, its an explanation and a workaround.

The example I provided wasn't 100% accurate, there's actually three classes. A base class, a second abstract class that inherits the base class, then finally the child class.

The base class was already included beforehand separate from the Autoload functionality, but the second abstract class needed to be included by the Autoload functionality which wasn't triggering.

When I disabled the logic that included the base class the Autoload functionality triggered and included  the base class and the second abstract class.

So going forward, I just need to make sure there isn't separate logic including files, and just let the Autoloader do its job.